# How to Get Chrome to Prioritize Order of Errors Shown for Security Certificates

Tags: tls, certificates

When you try to go to a website, chrome sometimes intercepts the connection and says there is a problem with the website's security certificate. This can be many things such as a common name error, outdated security certificate, or a self signed certificate.

However, if there are multiple errors, chrome only shows one of them based on which one it thinks is the most severe. How do I override this and get it to show a different error? For example, it always shows an error about an untrusted certificate authority over an outdated certificate, but I want it to show the outdated security certificate error over the untrusted certificate authority error.

Another solution would be completely ignoring one type of error. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The purpose of certificate validation in the browser is to check if the certificate is valid or not - but not to collect all reasons why the certificate might be not valid. That's why it will stop at the first problem it finds and report this. If you want to change the priority which errors are reported you would thus need to change the way certificate validation is done - that would means to change the TLS stack in the browser. There is no configuration for this you can easily apply.